# Rxkotlin Auto complete search

Tags: android, kotlin, search, autocomplete, system.reactive

I want to use Rxkotlin with autocomplete search that wait 3 seconds then search on this character inside arraylist and update the recyclerview .

I do all this work inside viewModel with DataBinding I try with this code:

```
  fun onSearchChange(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        val observable = Observable.create<String> { subsciber ->
            try {
                subsciber.onNext(s.toString())
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("tag", "err: ")
                subsciber.onError(e)
            }
        }.debounce(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe { Log.e("tag", "down: $it") }

        compositeDisposable.add(observable)
    }
```

but every time I try to hit any character it do like this :

H
HE
HEL
HELL
HELLO
** After 3 seconds **

But what I want After 3 seconds become just Hello.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is because your function every time creating new observable when `fun onSearchChange()` function invoked. Try to seperate your observable object like this

```
val emittedText = PublishSubject.create<String>()


fun onSearchChange(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
   emittedText.onNext(s.toString())
} 

fun observeTextChangeEvents() {
   val disposable = emittedText
       .debounce(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .subscribe { Log.e("tag", "down: $it") }
   compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
}
```

Comment: And when to call observeTextChangeEvents ?

Comment: If it is in your viewModel then in `init{ }` block

Comment: I tried it but not work